# Running javascript files with ES6 module imports in ASP.Net Core 2.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-core, ecmascript-6, .net-core

I would like to execute a script with NodeServices from .Net Core, which imports ES6 modules.

I managed to execute the script using NodeJs with a `--experimental-modules` flag.

Is there any equivalent using NodeServices?
Can my javascript file have import or dependencies from other scripts?

Answer (score 0):

So did you try setting an Environment Variable when adding the service?

```
services.AddNodeServices((xx)=>
{
    xx.EnvironmentVariables
});
```